# Using "Export.classifier.toAsset" to save a classifier into Asset and then use it later

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

How can I use `Export.classifier.toAsset` to save a classifier into Asset and then use it later?

Since GEE has provided this code ("Export.classifier.toAsset"), it should work. Now I can save a Random Forest classifier into my Asset, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: There are details and code examples in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/classification#saving-classifiers) and in the [API reference](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/export-classifier-toasset) that show how to save and load classifiers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var trainedRF = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(25).train({
  'features': trainSample,
  'classProperty': 'Class',
  'inputProperties': features
});

// Using the classifier defined earlier, export the  
// classifier as an Earth Engine asset.

Export.classifier.toAsset(
  trainedRF
);
```

// now you can load this classifier and use it on any other image

```
var classifierAssetId = "projects/rajani/assets/Wheat_V2_classfier_Export";

var savedClassifier = ee.Classifier.load(classifierAssetId);

var classified=S2_bands.classify(savedClassifier).clip(AOI)
```

Comment: Kindly mention how this code helps solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var classifierAssetId = "projects/rajani/assets/Wheat_V2_classfier_Export";

var savedClassifier = ee.Classifier.load(classifierAssetId);

var classified=S2_bands.classify(savedClassifier).clip(AOI)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).